# Issues When Changing from forEach to Jquery.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently had to replace my use of

```
arr.forEach( function( elm ) {...});
```

in JavaScript code to

```
$.each( arr, function( elm ) {...});
```

to make it **IE8** compatible.

This change is giving me numerous bugs.

Comment: Docs! `$.each(x, function(index,value)` -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Though it was possible to guess what was causing the bugs, in the future, you should actually tell us what the bugs are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bugs are due to the subtle difference in signature between JavaScript's `forEach` and Jquery's `$.each`: the order of the arguments in [Javascript's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback is

```
function( elementOfArr, indexInArr, Arr)
```

whereas with [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) it's reversed:

```
function( indexInArr, elementOfArr )
```

While we're at it, when it comes to `Jquery.grep()`, the [order](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) *is*

```
function( elementOfArr, indexInArr )
```

Comment: Yep. I've never understood why jQuery has it around that way since you are probably likely to be more interested in the element than the index in most cases, so it would make sense for the element to be first.